# Language(s)/Framework suited for interactive mobile map

Tags: java, android, c++, ios, dictionary

I have been tasked with creating an interactive 2D map application for a set of interlinked buildings with multiple floors for Android and iOS devices. The application should eventually feature a Google Street View interface and possibly 3D modeled viewing options.

My question is in regards to the best programming languages or pre-existing framework suited to this task, what would you recommend? I have approximately two years to complete this task, so picking up another language would not be a problem.

Required application features:

- Interactive 2D map of multiple buildings and floors.
- Google Street View type function.
- Pathfinding with similar functions to Google Maps.
- Android and iOS support with Android as primary development platform.

Optional application features:

- Interactive 3D map of multiple buildings and floors modeled by 3D artist.
- Ability to adapt into website based application.

This is an absolutely massive undertaking, optional features are just that - optional. The project is for a college, it'll may also sit on a big touch screen pedestal so needs to be stable and low maintenance I'm asking a lot, I know.

I'm currently siding with C#/++.

What do you people think?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be much better off looking at your project from a content-development perspective rather than application-development.

Develop your maps and 3D content and publish as KML documents referencing COLLADA 3D models.

You can then view/test using existing Google Maps and Google Earth viewers, including mobile versions (e.g. http://www.google.com/mobile/earth/)

There are also ways of providing custom Street Views or Street View Overlays (e.g. http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2012/07/custom-street-view-tutorial.html )

If existing free applications already do a great job at addressing you use-cases on multiple platforms, then you'd be wasting your time reinventing.  On the other hand, if you really want to write a custom app, you'll probably still want some custom content, and its worthwhile for your content to be in a "standard" format, so you won't lose anything if you begin by developing the content in Google compatible formats.

Answer (score 0):

For indoor maps, I strongly suggest you start by looking at the indoor map support that Google has implemented.

http://maps.google.com/help/maps/floorplans/

It may help to to get an Android version up and running with a very low effort.

If you want to write your own, you need to learn both Java and Objective C, or use a middleware that can  be ported between the platforms, such as [Xamarins](http://xamarin.com/)

If you use the Xamarin middleware, you can use C#.